# Splitting a list based on a delimeter into n chunks in Haskell. How can I write my functions more effeciently?

Tags: haskell, functional-programming

`Split`: Write a function split that takes a delimiter value `“c”` and a list `“iL”`, and it splits the input list with respect to the delimiter `“c”`.

Example output:

```
split 0 [1,2,3,0,4,0,5,0,0,6,7,8,9,10]
[[1,2,3],[4],[5],[],[6,7,8,9,10]]
```

My `split` function:

```
split :: Eq a => a -> [a] -> [[a]]
split a iL = let 
             helper a [] buf = (reverse buf):[]
             helper a (x:xs) buf = if x==a 
                                   then (reverse buf):(helper a xs [])   -- reverse 
                                   else (helper a xs (x:buf))
             in helper a iL []  -- use helper
```

`nSplit`: Write a function `nSplit` that takes a delimiter value `“c”`, an integer `“n”`, and a list `“iL”`, and it splits the input list with respect to the delimiter `“c”` up to `“n”` times.

Example output:

```
nSplit 0 3 [1,2,3,0,4,0,5,0,0,6,7,8,9,10]
[[1,2,3],[4],[5],[0,6,7,89,10]]
```

My nSplit function:

```
nSplit :: (Ord a1, Num a1, Eq a2) => a2 -> a1 -> [a2] -> [[a2]]
nSplit a2 a1 iL = let 
                  helper a2 a1 [] buf = (reverse buf):[]
                  helper a2 a1 (x:xs) buf = if x==a2&&a1/=0 
                                            then (reverse buf):(helper a2 (a1-1) xs [])
                                            else (helper a2 a1 xs (x:buf))
                  in helper a2 a1  iL []  -- use helper
```

Is there any possible way I can make improvements to this code since I did these to the best of my ability with barely any knowledge of Haskell. My professor approved of my code but he said it could be condensed somehow. Does anyone have any ideas of what changes I could make to my code if there are even any? They seem to pass all the provided test he gave us.

Comment: Does he approve of you asking online about your code?